# is this approach correct for connection management in orient DB?

Tags: multithreading, orientdb

I am using OrientGraphFactory to manage pool of connection

```
OrientGraphFactory graphFactory = new OrientGraphFactory(url,username,password).setupPool(DEFAULT_MIN_POOL_SIZE, maxPoolSize);
```

and i have a function which checks the active connection on thread and returns it

```
 public OrientGraph openDatabase() {
    OrientGraph db  = (OrientGraph)OrientGraph.getActiveGraph();
    if(db==null || db.isClosed())
    {
        db = graphFactory.getTx();
    }
    return db ;
 }
```

in my functions do i have to close/shutdown connection after use or it will be shutdown after the thread is terminated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach is incorrect because you use internal API.
More simple version `db = graphFactory.getTx();` takes in account all check which you done above.

Comment: ok , do i have to shutdown db  after using ?
    db.shutdown()

Comment: I tried with db.getTx() , its giving different connection on single thread eveytime .  
In multi thread environment i want to reuse connections for given thread , thats why I was trying with 

    OrientGraph.getActiveGraph()

Comment: You have to do the shutdown. Why do you think that it is giving different connections ?

Comment: sorry , its giving same instance , i checked it wrongly, 
thank you :)